# Passing through the onClick destination URL into the cookie

Tags: javascript, var

Anyone know what would be the best way using javascript to pass through the onClick destination URL into a javascript var where I can then write into a session cookie?

So when an user clicks on `[Button 1]` with the destination being `https://www.w3schools.com/js/` - ideally it would pass through `www.w3schools.com/js/`

What I've tried:

```
<script>  
 var destinationURL = window.location.href
 sessionStorage.setItem('destination', 'destinationURL');
 var destination = "destination"; // Name of your cookie
 var destinationURL = destinationURL; // Value of your cookie
 var expirationTime = 2592000; // One month in seconds
 expirationTime = expirationTime * 1000; // Converts expirationtime to milliseconds
 var date = new Date(); 
 var dateTimeNow = date.getTime(); 
 date.setTime(dateTimeNow + expirationTime); // Sets expiration time (Time now + one month)
 var expirationTime = date.toUTCString(); // Converts milliseconds to UTC time string
 document.cookie = cookieName+"="+cookieValue+"; expires="+expirationTime+"; path=/; domain=." + location.hostname.replace(/^www\./i, ""); // Sets cookie for all subdomains
</script>
```

Comment: What, if anything, have you tried so far, and what in particular are you struggling with

Comment: Added what I've tried.